# PHP cannot upload picture width larger than 3002 x 2893 pixels

Tags: php, upload

I have code, written by someone else that I have to modify. It won't upload files with width larger than 3002px and height larger than 2893px.

How did I test it: I had two different images with two different file sizes (width:3002px, height:2009px). When I set both on 3003px width, they won't upload, but if I set their width 3002px, they both will upload.

Then I rotated image (width:2009px, height:3002px) they didn't upload. Then I played with their heights and found that if I set height to 2893px (width will be 1934px in that case), it will upload, but if I set height to 2894px, it won't.

Here is my code:

```
error_reporting(0); 
$change=""; 
define ("MAX_SIZE","9999999999");

function getExtension($str) 
    { 
        $i = strrpos($str,"."); 
        if (!$i) { return ""; } 
        $l = strlen($str) - $i; 
        $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l); 
        return $ext; 
    }
$errors=0;

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST") 
    { 
      $image=$_FILES["img_1"]["name"]; 
      $uploadedfile = $_FILES["img_1"]['tmp_name'];
        if ($image) 
          { 
            $filename = stripslashes($_FILES["img_1"]['name']);
            $extension = getExtension($filename); 
            $extension = strtolower($extension);
              if ( ($extension != "jpg") && ($extension != "jpeg") && ($extension != "png") && ($extension != "gif")) 
                {
                  $change='<div class="msgdiv">Unknown Image extension </div> '; $errors=1; 
                } 
              else 
                { 
                  if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" ) 
                    { 
                      $uploadedfile = $_FILES["img_1"]['tmp_name'];
                      $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploadedfile); 
                    } 
                  else if($extension=="png") 
                    { 
                      $uploadedfile = $_FILES["img_1"]['tmp_name'];
                      $src = imagecreatefrompng($uploadedfile); 
                    } 
                  else 
                    { 
                      $src = imagecreatefromgif($uploadedfile); 
                    } 
                echo $scr;
                list($width,$height)=getimagesize($uploadedfile);
                $newwidth=700; 
                $newheight=($height/$width)*$newwidth;
                $tmp=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight);
                $newwidth1=150; 
                $newheight1=($height/$width)*$newwidth1;
                $tmp1=imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth1,$newheight1);
                imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height);
                imagecopyresampled($tmp1,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth1,$newheight1,$width,$height);
                $stamp = imagecreatefrompng('img/stamp.png');
                $marge_right = 10;
                $marge_bottom = 10;
                $sx = imagesx($stamp);
                $sy = imagesy($stamp);
                imagecopy($tmp, $stamp, $newwidth - $sx - $marge_right, $newheight - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));
                $filenameb = "img_big/big_".(rand(0, 99999999))."."."$extension"; $filename1 = "img_tmb/small_".(rand(0, 99999999))."."."$extension";
                imagejpeg($tmp,$filenameb,100); 
                imagejpeg($tmp1,$filename1,100); 
                imagedestroy($src); 
                imagedestroy($tmp); 
                imagedestroy($tmp1); 
                imagedestroy($stamp);
          } 
      } 
  }
if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && !$errors) 
  { 
    $change=' <div class="msgdiv">Image Uploaded Successfully!</div>'; 
  }

$img_1b = $filenameb; 
$smollimg_1 = $filename1; 
unset($filename); 
unset($filename1);
```

I don't have any idea what `MAX_SIZE` refers to. Maybe there is some flaw in code, maybe it is server-side issue?

Comment: Have you checked `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` yet? These are in your `php.ini`.

Comment: I set them to 128M to test if this is issue. I can't upload 110kb file that has 4000px width and 3000px height, but I can upload 3.25mb file that has 3002px width and 2009px height.

Comment: Also it might be worth looking at your memory limit.

Comment: @halfer how should I do it?

Comment: Have a look at your `memory_limit` in your `phpinfo()`, and then get a value for your [peak usage](https://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php) during a successful upload. If it's close then you might need to increase it, in your php.ini (some hosts permit its being changed in htaccess too).

Comment: @halfer Thank you so much. I increased `memory_limit` and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Great! Out of interest, what have you set it to? I tend to think that if it is much above 32-64M, then you're doing too much processing in the web layer, and you should push the work out to a scheduler or job queue. Cron is ideal for this, and it means you can fit lots more web processes into memory within your available RAM.

Comment: (I've moved your answer to an answer proper - we prefer not to add them as question edits. In future you are encouraged to do this yourself, and to self-accept).

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of OP.)*

I increased memory_limit and it worked. So if `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` doesn't work, try to increase `memory_limit`.